# Is "Generalized functions" by Gelfand published in 5 or 6 volumes?

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request

From what I know, "Generalized functions" by Gelfand is published in five volumes. Do you know whether there exist a 6th volume? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

The sixth volume is "Representation Theory and Automorphic Functions" by Gelfand, Graev, and Pyatetskii-Shapiro. It does not say in the title of the English translation that this is the sixth volume of the series by Gelfand and coauthors, but this is indicated inside the book and the original Russian version is clearer on this point. If you can read Russian, see the titles of the books by Gelfand on the page 
http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/ru/library/mathematics/calculus.htm.

Comment: how to download?

Comment: @maojun1998, you now have the title, so how you choose to acquire a copy (for free or by purchasing it) is your business.  The download links on the page I mentioned are pretty obvious, but if you don't read Russian then they're irrelevant to you.

Comment: haha.I get it.Tanks again.

Comment: The OP asked a good question. I also mentioned this at the end of my article https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.03180 when discussing Burnol's reformulation of the Riemann Hypothesis. I think this is a nice example of factoid which literally got "lost in translation".